# How to not graph unwanted information from an online csv

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

[Here](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv) is the data I'm required to use and I can't download it, it has to come from a server and be graphed on my website. As you can see I have two sources GCAG and GISTEMP. I have to graph either one but I don't know how to select the one I want to graph, so when I graph my data I get both ([graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs4BY.png)). I looked for if it's possible to temporarily store and clean the data then graph it but didn't find anything useful. What I want to do is only graph the means and years from the source GISTEMP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<section>
<div class='chartStyle'>
    <canvas id="GlobalTempGraph"></canvas>
</div>


</section>

</body>
</html>
```

```
var GlobalTempConfig = {

   type: 'line',

   plugins: [ChartDataSource],

   options: {
   legend: {
           display: false,
           reverse: true
         },  
     scales: {
         xAxes: [{
             scaleLabel: {
                 display: true,
                 labelString: 'Year',
             }

         }],
         yAxes: [{
             id: 'Temperature',
             gridLines: {
                 drawOnChartArea: false
             },
             scaleLabel: {
                 display: true,
                 labelString: 'Temperature',
             }
         }],

     },

     plugins: {
     datasource: {

         type: 'csv',
         url: 'https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv', //url of csv
         rowMapping: 'datapoint',
         datapointLabels: false,
         datapointLabelMapping: {
           _dataset: '_dataset',
           _index: 'x',
           x: '',
           y: ''}
   }
 }
   }

};


function effectsGraph(){
   var ctx = document.getElementById('GlobalTempGraph').getContext('2d');
   window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, GlobalTempConfig);
}

window.addEventListener("load", effectsGraph, false);
```

Comment: Having trouble following your question. You just want to chart one set of data at a time with some sort of way to switch between them?

Comment: @mkaatman I want to just chart GISTEMP but if there's a way to switch between them that would be even better.

Comment: So instead of pointing directly at the CSV, you'll need to manually load it and filter it prior to handing it off to the chart.